# Visualizing 3-D fit

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, fitting, curve-fitting

I have two independent variables, call them X and Y, and I have to fit a dependent variable Z = f(X,Y) somehow.

In an experiment, the experimentalist measured Z as a function of X, and another experimentalist measured Z as a function of Y.

Is it possible to combine these to somehow to actually find Z = f(X,Y)?

Thanks!
Thomas Moore

Comment: When the first experimentalist worked, did he fix or measure the value of $Y$?  When the second experimentalist worked, did she fix or measure the value of $X$?

Comment: Hello Matthew. No, Experimentalist 1 had no knowledge of Y, and Experimentalist 2 had no knowledge of X.

Comment: Do you have any information about the association between $X$ and $Y$? (eg. covariance)

Comment: Hello. No, we are only told that they are completely independent.